# Can not start postgresql due to perl error

Tags: postgresql, perl

I have installed postgres on my Ubuntu, when I try to run the `psql` command I am getting following error:

```
$ psql
Can't locate POSIX.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/POSIX.pm: Permission denied at /usr/bin/psql line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/psql line 20.
```

I have looked into the `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1` directory, there is no `POSIX.pm` file.

I have checked all `@INC` folder with following command:

```
$ perl -e 'print "@INC";' | tr " " "\n"
/usr/share/perl/5.22.1
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

I gave full permission to all the above directories with `chmod -R 777` option.
Still got the permission error.

If i fire following command then also getting error:

```
$ perl -e 'use POSIX'
Can't locate POSIX.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/POSIX.pm: Permission denied at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

Env details:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 58 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

$ uname -a
Linux anil-K55VM 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ apt list | grep postgresql-server

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

postgresql-server-dev-9.5/xenial-updates 9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04 amd64
postgresql-server-dev-all/xenial,xenial 173 all
```

Update:

```
root@anil-K55VM:~# ls -l /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/POSIX.pm
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/POSIX.pm': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/POSIX.pm`say?

Comment: @ridgy Updated original question with output of this command as you requested.

Comment: There seems something wrong with your perl installation. POSIX.pm in the given path is contained in package `libperl5.22` (and in `perl-base`, but with different installation path). Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall libperl5.22`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access to the local folder /user/local. I I checket the permission to the local folder and I didn't have all privileges to the folder so in this case you can make the next steps

go to te user folder... cd /user
after you can changes the privileges: sudo chmod 777 local
and you can try to connect again